# What's the name of a book about super endurance through relaxation?

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

I'm trying to remember the name of the book which is about a military commander who has found a way to push the limits of human endurance by completely relaxing his body. From what I can remember, his name was Cletus (I think), he had a bad knee, and he was teaching his entire squad the same relaxation technique.

Does my very limited summary ring a bell with anyone? I'm looking for the title and author.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for Gordon R. Dickson's [The Tactics of Mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactics_of_Mistake).  It is part of Dickson's Childe Cycle (which has a heavy emphasis on the Dorsai warrior culture).

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely the book I was thinking of.